# background-size not working properly in chrome

Tags: css, cross-browser

i have a left admin panel which is set in percentage width. the problem is that i have a repeating background in it and when i use background-size to tuck-in the background image to the size of percentage-based width, the image just disappears in chrome. in firefox it works fine. But when i use ctrl - to zoom-out the display, the image appears.
the css of the left panel is:

```
.adminmenuback {
    width: 30%;
    background: url(../images/leftpanel_bg.png) left top repeat-y;
    background-size: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
```

pls help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 100% 100% for background size.

```
.adminmenuback {
    width: 30%;
    background: url(../images/leftpanel_bg.png) left top;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aEJRB/

Comment: Bust that just makes the image spread the entire width/height, so even if you put no-repeat it will work, but in many cases it will cause the image to look bad.

Answer (score 0):

try this

background-size:contain;

Answer (score -1):

```
background-size: cover;
```

Try this.

Comment: Leave wild 'try this' answers in the comments and use answers only if you are fairly sure about what the problem is and know this will fix it. "cover" will not solve the problem in the question.

Comment: ok sure, thanks for the tip. background-size:cover; I'm pretty sure will still solve the issue, however.